# Programmatically adding textView; textView cannot be applied anonymous.okhttp3.Callback

Tags: android, json, android-layout

I am trying to get my results from an api returned on my app, so that each would be in its own `textView`. Later I want to add a button to each as well, but right now I'm just trying to get the results displayed on my app. In my `try` statements everything seems to be fine except on line `final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this)` `this` gives me an error(gets underlined in red) saying `TextView android.content.Context textView cannot be applied anonymous.okhttp3.Callback`. I'm not really sure what's wrong and how to fix it. I would appreciate any help! Thanks! Here's my code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream");
                    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{}");
                    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).get().build();


                            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                                @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();

                                }

                                @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                                    Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                                    for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                                        System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                                    }

                                    //System.out.println(response.body().string());
                                    //System.out.println(response.body().toString());
                                    String jsonData  = response.body().string();
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                                        JSONArray Jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("results");
                                        final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[Jarray.length()];
                                        for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                                            JSONObject object = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                            System.out.println(object.toString());
                                            final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);
                                            rowTextView.setText(object.toString());
                                        }
                                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);

                                    }


                                }
                            });
```

Comment: Please do not deface your own posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case "this" is the instance of anonymous.okhttp3.Callback class, use something like "YourFragmentClass.this.getActivity()" instead.

Comment: My class is called `Search` and it extends `Fragment`; I tried changing it to 'Search.this' but now it says that it cannot be applied to Search

Comment: TextView constructor parameter should be instance of Context class, you can obtain it from fragment instance with "getActivity()" method. I updated original answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

> final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);
>   rowTextView.setText(object.toString());

makes no sense. You create `TextView` and that's fine. You then sets some text. Ok. But what about displaying it? TextView is just an object an by itself does no magic to show up. I recommend you add TextView to your layout (hidden if needed) and then set the message and show it up if there's time.

**EDIT**

Your code will not work also because `this` in `new TextView(this)` refers to `okhttp3.Callback`, not the `Context` (i.e. your Activity).

Comment: I haven't written any code to display it because I was already having problems with `new TextView(this)` part and trying to solve that first.